# How to read socket data with socket_recvfrom?

Tags: php, sockets

I need to get information from UDP socket, but the fact that i do not know how many answers will receive so i decided to wait for a few seconds. The main problem is that `socket_recvfrom` blocks and all the code stuck... Is there some way to wait for a few second and stop the socket?

My code:

```
$end_time = time() + 2;

while ($end_time > time()) {
    socket_recvfrom($socket, $buffer, 2500, 0, $from, $port);
    var_dump($buffer);
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php
Look at the flags section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the function to non blocking mode using the [`MSG_DONTWAIT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php) flag:

```
$end_time = time() + 2;

while ($end_time > time()) {
    socket_recvfrom($socket, $buffer, 2500, 0, $from, $port, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    var_dump($buffer);
    // sleep 500ms to decrease cpu usage
    usleep(500000);
}
```